# Ios: Use textfield as searchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

in my project i am using a UITextField which i have to use it as UISearchBar as when i start typing a UITableView will open and show the search string.

i have a NSDictionary named as dictionary which looks like as

```
{
    268 = "David b Augustat";
    449 = "Rocky Balboa";
    489 = "Test Aayush";
    493 = "Mohit Driver";
    494 = "Tst ";
    495 = "Mohit DriverA";
    496 = "Test Kailash Driver";
    497 = "Pramod Sinha";
    498 = "Tty Ffff";
}
```

and two NSArray DrivernameArray and DriverIdArray which contain name and id from the dictionary

When i display the search results in tableview search by name is working fine and shows correct result but the associated id with that name does not update with name it remains same always

I am using the following code

```
NSDictionary *listing = [dict6 objectForKey:@"result"];
    DriverNameArray = [listing valueForKey:@"full_name"];
    DriverIdArray = [listing valueForKey:@"id"];



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverNameArray];
    //NSString *stringTovSearch = textField.text;

    tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:DriverIdArray];

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",driverTf.text]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

    NSArray *tempresults = [DriverNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (tempresults.count > 0)
    {
        tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
        tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults];
    }
    [SEarchTable reloadData];
    return  YES;
}


    -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:   nil];
    }
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


    {
        UILabel * idlbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 10)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:idlbl];
        idlbl.hidden = false;

        if (tempArray.count > 0)
        {

            cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            idlbl.text = [DriverIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];
        }
        else
        {
            idlbl.text = [DriverIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [DriverNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to merge both array id and name then filter that array.

Answer (score 0):

**Change type array**

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray,*tempId;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    tempId = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

**While Filter**

```
 [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    [tempId removeAllObjects]

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full_name = %@",driverTf.text]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate
     NSArray *mergedResultArray = [listing  ]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

     // now different array 
    if (tempresults.count > 0)
        {
           tempArray = [mergedResultArray valueForKey:@"full_name]";
            tempId = [mergedResultArray valueForKey:@"id"];
        }
```

**OR Another Possible Solution for your code**

```
if (tempArray.count > 0)
        {

            cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            idlbl.text = [tempId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // made changes here
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];
        }
        else
        {
            idlbl.text = [DriverIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [DriverNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
```

Comment: how to merge both arrays

Comment: can you add code that shows where you assign value to DriverIdArray.

Comment: or also try my another solution which i mentioned .

Comment: did you get date from json ?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate:'

Comment: can you add row json format because i m little confused with listing .

Comment: i think this should be NSArray *listing = [dict6 objectForKey:@"result"];

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code.

1. When you filter you only assign the array that holds names:

   ```
   if (tempresults.count > 0)
   {
       tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults]; // This seems to be used outside this method and in the cell for row method on access
       tempId = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempresults]; // This is a local variable and has no effect outside this mehod. Did you mean DriverIdArray =...
   }
   ```
2. You do actually only filter the name array and not the IDs array

   `NSArray *tempresults = [DriverNameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`

   Assume `DriverNameArray` has 10 elements and then `DriverIdArray` must have 10 of them. A filtered array `tempArray` may then have 5 items while the `DriverIdArray` still has 10. You should remove the same indices.

There are many ways to solve this and personally I suggest you to use a single array with custom object that holds both name and ID. Then filter that array.

For a quick fix though you may just find the index of object of your name in the original names array and apply the same index in the ID array (I discourage you to do so):

```
NSString *name = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSInteger indexOfName = [DriverNameArray indexOf:name];
NSString *identifier = [DriverIdArray objectAtIndex:indexOfName];
```

**Edit: In code**

To insert this into your code you only need to modify the part in the cell for row method:

```
        if (tempArray.count > 0)
        {
            NSString *name = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSInteger indexOfName = [DriverNameArray indexOf:name];
            NSString *identifier = [DriverIdArray objectAtIndex:indexOfName];

            cell.textLabel.text = name;
            idlbl.text = identifier;
            cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 14.0 ];
        }
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'indexOf:'

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap Have you tried to search the web to find which method it is used to get the index of object? It looks like indexOfObject might be the case. SO is not meant for you to get the code you will copy paste into your project! Look at the code and descriptions people are posting to you, understand the code, try implementing the code! If you have any issues then ask questions AFTER you have done some research!